# Software to draw processor schematics (where to ask this)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for a good free online or offline tool to draw processor schematics like this:

[image]

Comment: Product recommendations are not supported on most sites. If you rephrase it then you might find the answer you need on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), which is in open beta. Their requirements are pretty stringent, though, so be sure to read their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).